# Don't want null when used case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table data like that you show in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of table]

and I have query like this so I don't want null values in output, means I don't want field like this

[image: Do not want this]

Comment: Post your tables and code as formatted text, not images

Comment: you can use `IS NOT NULL` is your select.

Comment: Have you considered telling what you want? Just saying you don't want something isn't really a question at all.

Comment: my query here                                                                                                                                        SELECT (CASE WHEN sgm.Parameter='+' THEN sgm.Description        ELSE  ''  END) as[Allowance],
(CASE WHEN sgm.Parameter='-' THEN sgm.Description ELSE '' END )as[Deduction] 
FROM Cygnus_HR_Salary_Structure_Master_General sgm GROUP BY sgm.Parameter,sgm.Description

Comment: sir.. actually i want   Employees's State Insurance Corporation in 1st row as deduction than loan in 2nd row as deduction  bcoz that have parameter as '-'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: http://rextester.com/SAA54858                                                                see this link please say how can i mix both query's... please help me,,,,i try more than 2 days...but i cant getting output....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data next to each other using a trick with row_number(), so that you'll assign numbers to both + and - groups, and then group by it:

```
select
    max(case when Parameter = '+' then Description end),
    max(case when Parameter = '-' then Description end)
from (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Parameter order by Id) as RN
    from
        #tmp
) X
group by RN
```

[Example](http://rextester.com/FFX35671)

Comment: sir... its work but i have bit of problem please help me solve it..

Comment: when i put your code as sub query than getting error like                        subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: http://rextester.com/SAA54858

Comment: http://rextester.com/SAA54858                                                                see this link please say how can i mix both querys

Comment: You just have to add more columns to the select clause, you can't use this as an inner select. If you're not able to solve that, then add also test data to your example.

Comment: its done sir....thank you so much...